# IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 store the iml file in a separate folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import, module

I have done some research on this question but did not find any satisfying solution. Funny thing is that it worked two weeks ago with the last version of IDEA.

Works: With IDEA 2019.2.2 I was able to create a new empty project and give a folder location where my .idea stuff was stored.
Then I imported my code directory with a maven structure as module (Project Structure -> Modules -> (+) import module -> select path -> import module from external model -> maven -> next -> Keep project files in ...) and was able to give the storage path for the .iml-files.

Does not work: With IDEA 2019.3.1 I create an new empty project, I am still able to give the project file path, but when I import the source as a module, it's not possible to give a project file location anymore. After chosing ...-> import module from external model -> maven, there is no 'next' button but only a 'finish' button.

Result is that the .iml-files are stored into the source folders, which I want to avoid.

Is this wanted behaviour or a bug? Is there a way since the 2019.3.1 version to take the location of .iml-files out of the source directory where they are stored by default?

I have also tried to move the .iml-files manually and then edit the modules.xml. This resulted in a lot of error-prone path editing in the .iml files. That way can imho not be a solution.

Thanks for any hints, Patrick